# Is there a way to animate knife tool cut (or similar effect)

Tags: animation, knife-tool

I am trying to get an effect where in edit mode a plane is cut with some pattern from the edge and then the pre-built animation will reenact that cut from original plane to that final form, following the line of the cut. The "following the cut" part is the hard one, as all the *gradual reveal* techniques break once new vertices are added by the cut (weight painting, vertex group assignments, shape keys, etc).

[image: knife cut example]

It is ok if the actual cut is done on a separate plane copy and then applied with animation somehow. I can get somewhere close with overly complicated boolean overlap stamp, but then cutting the stamp itself has to be done in reverse but it will still not appear cleanly.

Or similarly with cut already done and shape keys to put dots back on the boundaries, but again, it does not "follow the cut".

Comment: can u show us (or link) a video how it should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options here.

1. Create a material with an alpha clip texture to aimate the cut.
2. separate the plane and the cut into objects and animate them seperately.
3. Shape keys but where you drag the border vertecies inward.

Comment: I tried the shape key approach, but it is not something cut and done. The shape keys need to be applied after cut and moved back, etc. The material approach looks more interesting but I am not sure how that would work in terms of smooth animation. Would you be able to share some more details on that specific one?

Comment: can you visualise for me how the animation should look, then i can make a file for you.

Comment: I have my - current - progress at https://www.blendswap.com/blend/29463 (video on 3rd slide), you can see the cut just jump into place around 7th second. I wanted some sort of progressive reveal instead and could not figure it out. @roel-deden

Comment: I made a mockup of what you need. https://we.tl/t-0VpC1JSIxy
You can make any kind of drawing on the UV texture and it will unfold the cuts accordingly. You can animate the pattern in the shader editor.